# Scanner doesn't reach the last line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have following code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int k = sc.nextInt();
    String s = sc.next();
```

I get `n` strings like "2 0101010" as input and i want to save `2` to variable `k` and `0101010` to string `s`, but scanner doesn't reach the last line. How can i fix it?

Comment: It’s going to read 2 into `n`, 0101010 into `k`, and then wait for additional input to read into `s`

Comment: I meant that `n` is going to be written as input first and it works, but problem is that scanner doesn't read the last line of input

Comment: Your code as written works (I ran it on input '1 (newline) 2 010101010 (newline)').  'n, k, s' are read as expected.  I added a print call after the assignment to 's'.   What do you mean "doesn't reach the last line"

Comment: @notAPPP - the meaning is clear enough. I'm not a fan of Scanner either, but it's clear what it's supposed to do (read 3 separate tokens in sequence) and it does it.

Comment: How are you testing it?  If by feeding it input interactively then the issue is likely that `Scanner.next()` is trying to consume a whole trailing delimiter (by default, a *run* of whitespace characters) before it accepts that it has seen a delimiter at all.  If your input is organized into lines then use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`, and trim (or just ignore) any trailing whitespace.

Comment: [mre] code post please.

Comment: What is the program supposed to do?  If the user inputs `5`, is the user expected to give 10 additional inputs? Please edit the question to explain.  Also, as a previous comment said, please provide a complete, but minimal reproducible example. (See the page linked to in that comment.) Include examples. Each example should have an input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: User friendly design tip: Precede each input request with a prompt.  For example, `Sysytem.out.print ("Input foo count (integer) >"); foo = sc.nextInt (); System.out.print ("Input bar value (floating point) >"); bar = sc.nextDouble ();`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I get `n` strings like "2 0101010" as input and i want to save `2` to variable `k` and `0101010` to string `s`, but scanner doesn't reach the last line. How can i fix it? ..."*

The code appears to work fine.

Here is a similar implementation.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt(), k;
String s;
while (n-- > 0) {
    k = in.nextInt();
    s = in.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the code sc is the scanner object, and fisrt int value is stored into variable n, if it is int, second value passed is stored into variable K and you must pass one more value to s. so you have to input three values.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"I get n strings like "2 0101010", as you said this I'm assuming that you are getting n number of strings, where a single string is of the form "2 0101010".

In this case if I were you, I would take the whole String as input and then perform string operations on it, and then storing them into k and s. You can use charAt and substrings to achieve this. Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).